# What is the difference between 星心相印 and 心心相印？

Tags: difference, taiwanese

The title is all that is necessary, but the following description can give context. I know the phrase, 「心心相印」means something to the effect of "two hearts beating in unison" which might be said of a parent and a child, lovers, or lifelong friends. 星 here, has replaced 心. The two sound very similar, but in what context is this appropriate? Does the meaning change? I saw this variation in this situation: I am friends with a Chinese-Taiwanese female who is an all-around great human. Intelligent, ambitious, industrious, amiable, etcetera. However, I think she might be interested in turning this into a romantic relationship solely because I am Caucasian. She occasionally gives me out-of-the-blue complements about my appearance. Maybe I am looking into it too much and she just wants to be good friends. Recently, she went on vacation and returned with a couple gifts for me. One was a vial of shells and small dried starfish. On the vial was a sticker which read, 「星心相印」. Can this be a friendly gesture or is it certainly romantic?

Comment: 星心相印 seems to be a song, and a very saucy song at that! Seems to have exactly the same meaning just a "cute" little play on words - so yeah I'd say she's coming on to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such phrase in Chinese as "星心相印"。

However, as the comment says, there is a song called that and it is definitely a romantic one. It expressed an admiration to the 'one' who gives the singer great comfort and warm feelings.

Besides, the gift is a `"star"fish` right?  "star" = "星", and the shells may look alike with the shape of heart. And I wonder if there is any "星" in any of your names.

My point of view, if it is a hand made (or wrote) by herself, it is 100% percent romantic, you have my words. Otherwise if it is only some cheap product(no offense) from a workshop of god-knows-where, than you have to consider if you had misread the signal~